# How to add image watermark using SixLabors Imagesharp package in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller, imagesharp

The code being used to create image using SixLabors.ImageSharp(1.0.0-beta0006) nuget is as below

```cs
using (var image = Image.Load(filePath, out var imageFormat))
{
    image.Mutate(imageProcess => imageProcess.Resize(new ResizeOptions
    {
        Mode = ResizeMode.Max,
        Size = CalculateDimensions(image.Size(), targetSize)
    }));
    var pictureBinary = EncodeImage(image, imageFormat);
    SaveThumb(thumbFilePath, thumbFileName, imageFormat.DefaultMimeType, pictureBinary);
}
```

I also want to add an image watermark on the current image with some opacity.
I tried several ways but was unable to do it.
Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: Hi, please consider opening an issue under https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues

Comment: Thanks @Anduin, I have opened the issue, but still no replies. https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/1056

Comment: @Anduin The issue tracker is not for questions. We have a dedicated Gitter channel. https://gitter.im/ImageSharp/General

Comment: Did you ever come right?